# Android Studio proxy error

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy

I have the IP of the proxy I use but I can't seem to get Android studio to use it. I get the following error :

> Error:Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please
>   configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I have pinged successfully the proxy, tried to set it up through "Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appareance and behaviour -> System settings -> HTTP Proxy", and even tried with the following code in the gradle file :

```
defaultConfig {
    systemProp.https.proxyHost="10.x.x.x"
    systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
    systemProp.http.proxyHost="10.x.x.x"
    systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing to make this work ?

Comment: is proxy port correct ? try with only 80

Comment: The port is explicitly 8080. I tried anyway with 80 as you suggested, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: post the detail error log ?

Comment: It was my mistake. As you suggested I read the detailed log and found out I didn't set in the gradle.properties of the project.properties the https systemProp. As a result it couldn't connect to all https url. Regarding this thread, how should I close it/ solve it ?

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND Create an answer to your question and then accept it as the correct answer. The correct solution is to define both HTTP & HTTPS proxy settings.